# javascript wont change localstorage value

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage

```js
const checkedStorage = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

if (checkedStorage === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false)
}
function darkMode() {
    if (checkedStorage === true) {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false)
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", true)
    }
}
```

When the value is manually set to false and I press the button to run darkMode(), it will change to true but if it is set to true, it won't change to false. When it is set to null it changes to false, which means if it is true and the function is run shouldnt it work? I am honestly stumped. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because when you fetch data from `localStorage` using `localStorage.getItem` it returns a string. So `"true" === true` is false, that's the reason why the value is not being set to `false`. For more info about `getItem` please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Please change the condition to like below

```
function darkMode() {
    if (checkedStorage === "true") {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false)
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", true)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have remember that value in localstorage is a String and isn't boolean. That's you issue. This code will help u

```js
const checkedStorage = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

if (checkedStorage === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false)
}
function darkMode() {

    if (checkedStorage === "true") {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false)
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", true)
    }
   
}

darkMode();
```

I hope help u. Pdta: Sorry for my english.